# PHP CURL does not support RTMP protocol

Tags: php, linux, curl

I am trying to fetch RTMP url using PHP CURL, but unfortunately php curl says >Protocol "rtmp" not supported or disabled in libcurl

I have installed rtmpdump and upgraded CURL to 7.47.1 latest stable version on my Centos 6.7 VPS.
Following is the response from curl -V shell command

> curl 7.47.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.1 OpenSSL/1.0.1e zlib/1.2.3 librtmp/2.3
>   Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
>   Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets

It clearly shows support for rtmp protocol, but when I check phpinfo() output it lists all the protocols given below under curl except rtmp,

> Protocols  dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smb, smbs, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp

I have tried everything, upgraded curl, rebuild curl with rtmplib support, upgraded php to 5.6 but have not got any success as yet.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the cURL version shown in PHP say 7.47.1 or is it still linked to the older cURL you had installed?

Comment: Yes it is point to the right version that is 7.47.1